# Python - how can two subclass update each other but not affect the third one

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a base class Procedure, and three subclass subProcA, subProcB, and subProcC inherited from Procedure. For each procedure, it has start/end trigger. If one procedure starts, I will first check if the previous procedure has ended normally by using self.name. As I will reset procedure name (self.procedure = None) to indicate this procedure's end.

Also, I created three instances to track current currProcA, currProcB, currProcC.

My issue is subProcA and subProcB should be tracked together (they cannot be combined to the same subclass as subProcB has more attribute than subProcA), while subProcC is tracked separately. For example, I first received subProcA start trigger, followed by subProcB start trigger, and I should flag it as ERROR because subProcA has not ended yet. But my current implementation makes subProcA/B/C all be tracked independently - no error for receiving 'subProcA start' + 'subProcB start'.

So how can I fix it? Is there any minor change to implement this logic based on my current design? Thanks very much for your help.

```
class Procedure(object):
    def __init__(self, name=None):
        self.name = name
    def TriggerCheck(self, keyword=None):
        if keyword:
            thisProc, trigger = self.ProcedureName(keyword)
            # To check if the previous procedure ends
            if trigger == 'start' and self.name:
                if thisProc != self.name:
                    # flag error - new procedure started but previous one did not end.
                    self.reset()
                    self.name = thisProc

class subProcA(Procedure):
    ....
class subProcB(Procedure):
    ....
class subProcC(Procedure):
    ....

currProcA = subProcA()
currProcB = subProcB()
currProcC = subProcC()
```

Comment: This is not what classes are for. This is what queues are for.

Comment: Do you have any suggestion for implementation?

Comment: That's a separate question that depends on what exactly you are trying to do and what your constraints are. You could try looking into [`celery`](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/index.html) as that is a pretty popular library for this sort of thing.

Comment: Thanks lanAuld for your suggestion. But I think i will go with a new class named procedureManager to achieve my purpose.